# Eclipse: How to show project's SVN repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, project

I have quite a few Java projects on Eclipse and i use different SVN repositories.

When a project is Shared, i would like to know which SVN repository it uses. (appended in front of the project name?...)

Is there a simple way to do it?

NOTE: I use the "Package Explorer" View.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using SVN plugin then go to windows -> preferences -> Team -> SVN ->Label Decorations

In the text tab, for project format add variable 'url_short' that should do.

Answer (score 11):

Also, you might need to enable 'SVN' in General>Appearance>Label Decorations

Answer (score 0):

I use the subversive plugin for eclipse and it's shown by default.

Comment: That's not my case... i get the PROJECT NAME (inside brackets)